# Using mercator projection: I want to color only lands/countries, and all land(except Antarctica) plus all ocean gets colored

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, mercator

This code is from Basemap docs pages, with some changing to focus on my issue at hand.
I want to color(in this case, magenta) all lands(Antarctica can be overlooked), and all ocean should be white like Antarctica is right now. The shapefile is from [here](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes.zip)[image]

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-180,llcrnrlat=-85,urcrnrlon=180.,urcrnrlat=85, projection='merc')

map.readshapefile('countries_lakes/ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes', 'units')

patches = []

for info, shape in zip(map.units_info, map.units):
    patches.append(Polygon(np.array(shape), True))

ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, facecolor= 'm', edgecolor='k', linewidths=1.))

plt.savefig('dem.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Ok so you want to colorize, but you need to edit your code into the question and to be specific with input and output provided about what doesnt work

Comment: Why does the mercator Projection matter?

Comment: I just added it. Sorry I forgot before.

Comment: Mercator projection doesn't stretch any countries and shows the map flat, instead of sphere. I was using Cylindrical Equidistant before, but it stretched, for example, Russia, horizontally. Cylindrical Equidistant actually stretched much as it got near the poles I guess.

Comment: Well yes That’s what Mercator does but why is that significant to the problem you are having colouring the shapes?  Does your code work with a non-mercator projection? What have you tried to debug the problem you are having? What happens if you just add a few shapes (i.e. not all of them)?

Comment: Did you try the `fillcontinents()` approach described here https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/first_map.html

Comment: I want to be able to choose what areas to color, ultimately. fillcontinents() just fills up everything in the land.

Comment: I made this change to the for loop, and some of the land areas got colored, and not the water, just as it should.
if i % 10 == 0:
        patches.append(Polygon(np.array(shape), True))
    i += 1

Comment: So, its somehow spilling the color into ocean regions while attempting to color some parts of land?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine with Cylindrical Equidistant projection. But that can confuse the user, since some countries seem stretched/flatter in it. That's why Mercator is the only option to go with.

Comment: You should have included that information in your question. Please edit the code update into your question and also add the things you have tried while attempting to get this to work. If you have solved the problem, add this to your question too.